# Error al llamar un método con laravel desde el mismo controlador

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un método pero es tan largo que el cual ya no es mantenible o un poco complejo por ser tan largo, lo que quiero es fraccionar el codigo con pequeños métodos, para ser mas comprensible, pero me da el error

> Call to undefined function Miproyecto\Http\Controllers\esmachote()

el codigo del metodo nuevo es el llamado esmachote y lo tengo de esta manera:

```
public function esmachote($plan){
    $guardado = Plantillas::find($plan);
    $guardado->description = $request->input('editor1');
    $guardado->save();
 }
```

y la llamada de ese metodo esta en un store que es el metodo gigantesco solo pondre la parte donde se llama el metodo `esmachote`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{     
  $machote = $request->input('machote');
  if($machote == 'SI'){
    $plan = $request->input('plantillas');
    esmachote($plan);
  }}
```

tengan en mente de que eso es solo una pequeña parte del metodo el metodo solo para que se den la idea lo pondré  por ejemplo el metodo si el no viene archivo el envia el correo sin el adjunto y si viene el envia el correo con el adjunto y pone la informacion al cliente en la plataforma la parte del cliente, para que tambien el la tenga ahi y en el correo. por eso si otra cosa seria separar los metodos de adjunto y no adjunto. pero da el mismo error

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {     
      $machote = $request->input('machote');
      if($machote == 'SI'){
        $plan = $request->input('plantillas');
        esmachote($plan);
      }
      $cliens =  $request->input('idclientes');
      $link = $request->input('adjunto');
      $gmail = $request->input('Emails');
      if($cliens != null && $link != null){
      foreach ($cliens as $clien[0]) {
        foreach ($link as $key[0]) {
        $anno = date('Y');
        $fecha = $request->input('fecha');
        $description = $request->input('editor1');
        $grupos = $request->input('grupos');
        $idgrupo = $request->input('idgrupo');
        $texto = $request->input('plantillas');
        $titulo = $request->input('subject');
        $calendario = $request->input('calendary');
        $id_boletin = $request->input('idarchivo');
        $clients = $request->input('conecta');
        $tablaboletins = $request->input('tablaboletin');
        $tablaboletin = new Boletin();
        $conecta = new Historica();
        foreach($clien as $cliente_id){
        foreach ($key as $lnk ) {
            $conecta->titulo = $titulo;
            $conecta->anno = $anno;
            switch ($texto) {
            case '1':
          $conecta->texto ='
          No hay cambios
          ';
          break;
        case '2':
          $conecta->texto = '
          No hay cambios requisitos pero sí informacion de interes
           ' ;
          break;
        case '3':
           $conecta->texto =  
            '
         Sí hay nuevos requisitos legales
           ';
          break;
      }
           if(!is_string($fecha)){
              $fecha = date('M');
            switch ($fecha) {
              case 'Jan': $conecta->fecha = '0'; break;
              case 'Feb': $conecta->fecha = '1'; break;
                case 'Mar': $conecta->fecha = '2'; break;
                case 'Apr': $conecta->fecha = '3'; break;
                case 'May':  $conecta->fecha = '4'; break;
                case 'Jun':  $conecta->fecha = '5'; break;
                case 'Jul':  $conecta->fecha = '6';  break;
                case 'Ago':  $conecta->fecha = '7';  break;
                case 'Sep':  $conecta->fecha = '8';  break;
                case 'Oct':  $conecta->fecha = '9';  break;
                case 'Nov':  $conecta->fecha = '10'; break;
                case 'Dec':  $conecta->fecha = '11'; break;}}
                else{
              switch ($fecha){
              case '0': $conecta->fecha = '0'; break;
              case '1': $conecta->fecha = '1'; break;
                case '2':$conecta->fecha = '2'; break;
                case '3':$conecta->fecha = '3'; break;
                case '4': $conecta->fecha = '4'; break;
                case '5': $conecta->fecha = '5'; break;
                case '6': $conecta->fecha = '6'; break;
                case  '7': $conecta->fecha = '7'; break;
                case '8': $conecta->fecha = '8'; break;
                case '9': $conecta->fecha = '9'; break;
                case '10': $conecta->fecha = '10'; break;
                case '11': $conecta->fecha = '11'; break;
              }
              }
              $tablaboletin->id_files_boletin = $id_boletin;
              $tablaboletin->id_grupo = $idgrupo;
              $tablaboletin->fecha = $calendario;
              $conecta->firma = $description;
              $conecta->grupo = $grupos;
              $conecta->idgrupo = $idgrupo;
              $conecta->link = $lnk;
              $conecta->calendario = $calendario;
              $conecta->id_boletin = $id_boletin;
              $conecta->cliente_id = $cliente_id;
              $conecta->save();
              $tablaboletin->save();
          }
         }
     }
   }
      $subject = $request->input('subject');
        $e_mail = $request->input('Emails');  
        $estipulo = $request->input('plantillas');
      $text = $request->input('editor1');
      $files = $request->input('adjunto');
      foreach ($e_mail as $key) {
            Mail::send('emails.envia',array(
               'key'   =>  $key,
               'subject' => $subject,
               'text'    =>  $text,
               'estipulo'    =>  $estipulo,
               'files'  =>  $files,
            ),
            function($msj)use($key,$estipulo,$text,$subject,$files){
              $msj->subject($subject);
              $msj->to($key);
              if($files) {
                foreach ($files as $attachment) {
                  $msj->attach(public_path('/storage/boletines/').$attachment, [
                              'as' => $attachment,
                              'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                      ]);    
                }
              }
            });
      }
      return Redirect::to('/Admin/reportes/create');
    }
    else{
     /// enviar archivos sin adjunto. 
    /*   ** *** ** * ***  ****   * */
      $cliens =  $request->input('idclientes');
      foreach ($cliens as $clien[0]) {
        $anno = date('Y');
        $fecha = $request->input('fecha');
        $description = $request->input('editor1');
        $grupos = $request->input('grupos');
        $idgrupo = $request->input('idgrupo');
        $texto = $request->input('plantillas');
        $titulo = $request->input('subject');
        $calendario = $request->input('calendary');
        $id_boletin = $request->input('idarchivo');
        $link = $request->input('adjunto');
        $gmail = $request->input('Emails');
        $clients = $request->input('conecta');
        $tablaboletins = $request->input('tablaboletin');
        $tablaboletin = new Boletin();
        $conecta = new Historica();
        foreach($clien as $cliente_id){
            $conecta->titulo = $titulo;
            $conecta->anno = $anno;
            switch ($texto) {
            case '1':
          $conecta->texto ='
          No hay cambios
          ';
          break;
        case '2':
          $conecta->texto = '
          No hay cambios requisitos pero sí informacion de interes
           ' ;
          break;
        case '3':
           $conecta->texto =  
            '
         Sí hay nuevos requisitos legales
           ';
          break;
      }
           if(!is_string($fecha)){
              $fecha = date('M');
            switch ($fecha) {
              case 'Jan': $conecta->fecha = '0'; break;
               case 'Feb': $conecta->fecha = '1'; break;
                 case 'Mar': $conecta->fecha = '2'; break;
                  case 'Apr': $conecta->fecha = '3'; break;
                   case 'May':  $conecta->fecha = '4'; break;
                    case 'Jun':  $conecta->fecha = '5'; break;
                     case 'Jul':  $conecta->fecha = '6';  break;
                      case 'Ago':  $conecta->fecha = '7';  break;
                      case 'Sep':  $conecta->fecha = '8';  break;
                     case 'Oct':  $conecta->fecha = '9';  break;
                   case 'Nov':  $conecta->fecha = '10'; break;
                 case 'Dec':  $conecta->fecha = '11'; break;}}
               else{
              switch ($fecha){
              case '0': $conecta->fecha = '0'; break;
               case '1': $conecta->fecha = '1'; break;
                 case '2':$conecta->fecha = '2'; break;
                   case '3':$conecta->fecha = '3'; break;
                    case '4': $conecta->fecha = '4'; break;
                    case '5': $conecta->fecha = '5'; break;
                    case '6': $conecta->fecha = '6'; break;
                    case  '7': $conecta->fecha = '7'; break;
                   case '8': $conecta->fecha = '8'; break;
                  case '9': $conecta->fecha = '9'; break;
                 case '10': $conecta->fecha = '10'; break;
                case '11': $conecta->fecha = '11'; break;
              }
              }
              $tablaboletin->id_files_boletin = $id_boletin;
              $tablaboletin->id_grupo = $idgrupo;
              $tablaboletin->fecha = $calendario;
              $conecta->firma = $description;
              $conecta->grupo = $grupos;
              $conecta->idgrupo = $idgrupo;
              $conecta->link = "No hay Archivos";
              $conecta->calendario = $calendario;
              $conecta->id_boletin = $id_boletin;
              $conecta->cliente_id = $cliente_id;
              $conecta->save();
              $tablaboletin->save();
           }
          } 
       $subject = $request->input('subject');
      $e_mail = $request->input('Emails');  
      $estipulo = $request->input('plantillas');
      $text = $request->input('editor1');
      $files = $request->input('adjunto');
      if($e_mail != null){
      foreach ($e_mail as $key) {
          Mail::send('emails.envia',array(
               'key'   =>  $key,
               'subject' => $subject,
               'text'    =>  $text,
               'estipulo'    =>  $estipulo,
               'files'  =>  $files,

          ),
          function($msj)use($key,$estipulo,$text,$subject,$files){
              $msj->subject($subject);
              $msj->to($key);
          });
        return Redirect::to('/Admin/reportes/create');
      }
     }else{
      return Redirect::to('/Admin/clientgroup/genera');
    }
  }
}///fin de metodo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacer referencia al **método** de la misma **clase** con:

`self::esmachote($plan)`

Para referenciar a la **clase actual**, para **nombres estáticos**:

`this->esmachote($plan)`

Para hacer referencia al **objeto** (instancia) actual, para **nombres no estáticos**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{     
  $machote = $request->input('machote');
  if($machote == 'SI'){
    $plan = $request->input('plantillas');
    $this->esmachote($plan);
  }
}
```

Comment: En el contexto que está planteado es incorrecto usar `self::esmachote()`

Comment: ya lo explique!

Answer (score 1):

Para llamar un método dentro del mismo controlador, utiliza `$this` para hacer referencia al controlador en el que estás:

```
$this->esmachote($plan);
```